# svn move to non-existent directory

Tags: svn, move

I have used *svn move* before but not like that am I am asking here because I cannot afford to make a mistake:

I have a project which is a sub project of another one and should now be a top level stand alone project:

Current layout (nested):

```
/
└── company
    └── otherproject
        └── trunk
            └── project
```

Desired layout (separated):

```
/
└── company
    └── otherproject
    │   └── trunk
    └── project
        └── trunk
```

I am unsure whether I need to run `svn mkdir` first or does `svn move` create the new directories for you.

Also unclear how I should do the `svn commit` after the `svn move`.

Comment: Why do you cannot afford to make a mistake? It´s under version control.

Comment: Because it makes me look bad with the team if I have to revert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, as royalTS already said, the whole point of version control is about being able to roll back. That includes all kinds of changes you can think of. If revision 1234 decides everything (!) needs to be brutally purged (maybe it's that time of the year again), revision 1233 couldn't care less.

Now, to your problem:

You're saying the target directory does not exist. That is not the case. You want to move `project` to `company`. Obviously `company` already exists. No need to `mkdir` anything.

You have 2 options here.

1. Edit a local working copy:

   ```
   # cd to somwhere in the working copy, let's say `company`.
   cd /working-copy/company

   # move
   svn mv otherproject/trunk/project .

   # commit changes
   svn ci
   ```
2. Work with remote addresses (http is just an example here, it depends on the actual configuration)

   ```
   svn mv http://..../company/otherproject/trunk/project http://..../company
   ```

   This will commit immediately.

By the way, if you specify non-existing files or directories, subversion will throw an angry error message at you, like everyone else.

Maybe you should set up your own repo and run some experiments...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer... I ended up using the Subclipse plugin for Eclipse to do everything on the remote repository